# How get state in feature module? (ngrx)

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

I develop the application with angular and ngrx.

How get a state in feature module?

```
this.todos$ = this.store.select(state => state.todos.data)
```

I use this [tutorial](https://toddmotto.com/ngrx-store-understanding-state-selectors#state-slice-selectors) but I cannot understand what is `fromStore`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your reducer.ts export that

```
export function myList(state = [], action: Action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case 1:
        return data1;
    case 2:
        return data2;
    default:
        return state;
 }
}
```

your store.model.ts must be this:

```
 export interface AppStore {
     myList: element[];
     ...
 }
```

and you can get the state like this :

```
constructor(private store: Store<AppStore>) {}

this.todos$ = this.store.select("myList")
```

that will return an Observable of  elements array